# Automatically Close current window and open new window with new URL address

Tags: javascript, html

I was using following code for auto close current window and open new window with the new URL in the variable.

There is something wrong with the code, not working anymore it is closing but not reopening new window.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="prahma" content="no-cache">
    <title>Auto Close and Open New window</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

    <script language="javascript">
      var url = "http://www.myweb.com/weather_control.php?"+Math.random()
      window.open(url,"","");
      window.open('', '_self', ''); 
      window.close();
    </script>

  </head>
  <body onload="closeIt();">
  </body>
</html>
```

You need to accept "allow always popup for this site".

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `Math.random()`.  Also you might want to try calling the `closeIt()` function **after** you have opened the new window.  I think what is happening is that the window is being closed before it can open the new one.

Comment: oops!.....popup was blocked...i setup with always for this site...it works...

Comment: `language="javascript"` is deprecated

Comment: Your users will also have that problem if they have an ad blocker installed...

Comment: thats is not for user, this is for admin internal use only...Lix thansk

Answer (score 0):

you do know that http://www.myweb.com/weather_control.php is dead page, right?
Try to use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="prahma" content="no-cache">
<title>Auto Close and Open New window</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<script language="javascript">
  var url = "http://www.myweb.com/weather_control.php?"+Math.random()
  window.open(url,"","MyTitle");
  window.open('', '_self', ''); 
</script>

</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){window.close();},2000)">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function gio() {
        popup = window.open('http://www.wholewordz.cf/2017/02/kenya-says-it-will-shut-worlds-biggest.html');
        setTimeout( 5000);
      }
    
      function closed(){
        setTimeout("window.close()", 500);
      }
    
      function call() {
        popup = window.open('http://www.google.co.in');
        setTimeout(wait, 8000);
      }
    
      function caller() {
        setInterval(call, 12000);
      }
    
      function wait() {
        popup.close();
        closed();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="caller(); gio();">
  </body>
</html>
```