# Auto close browser window

Tags: javascript, html

I want to auto close a window in Firefox that is opened by a **window.open()** function. I have searched the Stack Overflow forum and found these links:

1) [How do I automatically close a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621554/how-to-close-automatically-a-webpage)
2) [Automatically Close current window and open new window with new URL address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487778/automatically-close-current-window-and-open-new-window-with-new-url-address)

But as I am not very much used to with JavaScript, I could not implement the code appropriately.

Please find below the code which opens up a window - that needs to be auto closed. But inserting a  in the resulting html file makes it invalid.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function Clickheretoprint(vpid,vage,vroom,vname,vsex,vdoc,vdat)
{

  var disp_setting="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,";
      disp_setting+="scrollbars=yes,width=300, height=200, left=100, top=25 resizable=yes";
  //var content_vlue = document.getElementById("T_PID").value;


   var docprint=window.open("","",disp_setting);
   docprint.document.open();
   docprint.document.write('<html>');
   docprint.document.write('<body style="margin:0.01in 0.01in 0.01in 0.01in; width:3in;height:2in;position:absolute;" onLoad="self.print()">');
   docprint.document.write('<table height="25%">');
docprint.document.write('<tr>');
   docprint.document.write('<td style=" font-weight: bold;" align="left">Regd : '+vpid+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date :'+vdat+'</td>');
   docprint.document.write('</tr>');
   docprint.document.write('<tr>');
   docprint.document.write('<td style=" font-weight: bold;" align="left">Name : '+initCap(vname)+'</td>');
   docprint.document.write('</tr>');
   docprint.document.write('<tr>');
   docprint.document.write('<td colspan=2 align="left"; ><B>Age :</B>'+vage+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<B>Category :</B>'+vsex+'</td>');
   docprint.document.write('</tr>');
   docprint.document.write('<tr>');
   docprint.document.write('<td colspan=2 style="font-weight: bold;" >'+vdoc+' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Room:'+vroom+'</td>');
   docprint.document.write('</tr>');
   docprint.document.write('</table>');
   docprint.document.write('<table height="25%">');
   docprint.document.write('<tr><td style="height:1in;width:100%;Font-family:CODE 39;"> <center>');
   docprint.document.write('<font face="CODE 39" size="7">');
   docprint.document.write('*'+vpid+'*');

   docprint.document.write('</font>');
   docprint.document.write('</center></td></tr>');
   docprint.document.write('</table>');
   docprint.document.write('</body></html>');
   docprint.document.close();
   docprint.focus();
}
```

Please let me know how to edit the resulting file so that it auto closes after 3 seconds.

Thanks!

PS: A little detailed answer will be appreciated as I am quite new to this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvLgG)

**Try it:**

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Open and Close after 3s</button>
<script>
    var myWindow;
    function openWin() {
        myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");
        myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
        setTimeout(closeWin, 3000);
    }

    function closeWin() {
        myWindow.close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried the CODEPEN?
In my browser (FF) it works, the window closed after 3s...
If you tried it in codeplayground such as JSfiddle and Stackoverflow it wont works because the page prevents script inside IFrame to opens and closes new window.

Comment: Oh...in CODEPEN it works.  But when I tried it in my computer it didin't. But just now I changed the entry dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows; in about:config and just appended the line setTimeout("window.close()", 3000); . What it does, it closes the parent window after 3 seconds. But I want the pop-up window to close.

Comment: `window.close()` will close the parent window.
If you want to close the pop-up window you should use the variable name as you declared when you open the new window. In my code I declared as `myWindow` and you can replace it with whatever you wish except `window`.